# Как удалять нужный поток в handler?

Tags: java, android

Запускаю несколько раз этот код в AsyncTask по нажатию кнопки со своими атрибутами.

```
int id=nomTel;

    handler.postDelayed(
             new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {                                 
                        Log.i(TAG, "спустя 10000 milliseconds"+id);
                            }
                         },
                        10000);
```

Создается несколько потоков, их можно удалить все вместе handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); но мне нужно удалять каждый по отдельности по ID который передается с нажатием кнопки, для этого используют

```
handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
```

Но у меня myRunnable как переменная отсутствует, мне нужно сделать в коде выше, что то вроде

```
 myRunnable = new Runnable() {...
```

Но как myRunnable превратить в id(номер телефона), чтоб я мог удалить по нему поток?

P.S. может у решении этой задачи есть другая логика...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. > Создается несколько потоков

   Нет, не создается. `handler.postDelayed` ставит в очередь на выполнение код, описанный в `Runnable` в том потоке, в котором работает этот `handler`. При этом совершенно точно другие потоки не создаются.
2. В `AsyncTask` это перемещать не имеет абсолютно никакого смысла. Это не даст ни чего, кроме десяти бесполезных строчек кода и искренного недоумения того, кто будет читать этот код после вас.
3. Чтобы сопоставить `Runnable` с какими либо другими данными, в вашем случае каким-то id (типа `integer`?), можно использовать `Map<Integer, Runnable>`:

   1. Создаете поле:

      ```
      Map<Integer, Runnable> runnableMap = new HashMap<Integer, Runnable>();
      ```
   2. При создании нового `Runnable`, добавляйте его в `runnableMap` :

      ```
      Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {...};
      runnableMap.put(/*тут ваш айдишник. Он является ключем*/, myRunnable);
      ```
   3. Чтобы отменить его, делаете так:

      ```
      Runnable myRunnable = runnableMap.get(/*тут ваш айдишник. Он является ключем*/);
      if(myRunnable != null) {
      handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
      }
      ```

Comment: И откуда только такие умные берутся?! :)